# Replace specific values with NA for specific columns

Tags: r, replace, na

I have  a big data frame that includes binary (0/1) items. However some columns contains 3. I want to change these 3 with NA for certain columns and applying the changes to the original data frame.

I have tries some solutions but they either applied to the whole dataset or creating a new data set with only the changes columns.

head of dataset looks like:

```
                          X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6
                      S1  1   45  0   1   1    3
                      S2  2   12  1   0   3    0
                      S3  3   3   0   0   1    1
                      S4  4   11  1   0   3    3
                      S5  5   13  0   1   1    3
                      S6  6   20  1   0   1    1
```

Desired output:

```
                          X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6
                      S1  1   45  0   1   1    NA
                      S2  2   12  1   0   NA   0
                      S3  3   3   0   0   1    1
                      S4  4   11  1   0   NA   NA
                      S5  5   13  0   1   1    NA
                      S6  6   20  1   0   1    1
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `dplyr`.

Here is a friendly `dput` of the data.

```
data <- structure(list(X1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 
           X2 = c(45, 12, 3, 11, 13, 20), 
           X3 = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), 
           X4 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), 
           X5 = c(1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1), 
           X6 = c(3, 0, 1, 3, 3, 1)), 
      class = "data.frame", 
      row.names = c("S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6"))

library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  mutate(across(X3:X6, ~na_if(., 3)))

  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
1  1 45  0  1  1 NA
2  2 12  1  0 NA  0
3  3  3  0  0  1  1
4  4 11  1  0 NA NA
5  5 13  0  1  1 NA
6  6 20  1  0  1  1
```

Comment: This worked fine only I have to assign it to new dataframe, cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `dplyr` using `across()`:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
df <- df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(across(X5:X6,~ifelse(.==3,NA,.)))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
# Rowwise: 
     X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1    45     0     1     1    NA
2     2    12     1     0    NA     0
3     3     3     0     0     1     1
4     4    11     1     0    NA    NA
5     5    13     0     1     1    NA
6     6    20     1     0     1     1
```

Comment: Thanks Duck, since I have so many columns is it possible to use columns numbers? like [, 3:64] for 61 columns? best

Comment: @MudarSaied Yeah, just change this in the code `across(c(3:64),~ifelse(.==3,NA,.))`

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can do

```
data[3:6][data[3:6] == 3] <- NA
```

-output

```
data
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
#S1  1 45  0  1  1 NA
#S2  2 12  1  0 NA  0
#S3  3  3  0  0  1  1
#S4  4 11  1  0 NA NA
#S5  5 13  0  1  1 NA
#S6  6 20  1  0  1  1
```

NOTE: Using `base R` will also retain the row names

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(X1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), X2 = c(45, 12, 3, 11, 
13, 20), X3 = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), X4 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), 
    X5 = c(1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1), X6 = c(3, 0, 1, 3, 3, 1)),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c("S1", 
"S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6"))
```